# Flask SQLAlchemy force join

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following two classes. What I'm trying to do is have my curriculum.name field always appear in my queries for curriculumareaoflearning

```
class Curriculum(db.Model, SerializableModel):
  __tablename__ = "curriculum"
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
  iscurrent = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
  notes = db.Column(db.Text)
  areasoflearning = db.relationship('CurriculumAreaOfLearning', lazy='dynamic')

class CurriculumAreaOfLearning(db.Model, SerializableModel):
  __tablename__ = "curriculumareaoflearning"
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
  curriculumid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('curriculum.id'), nullable=False)
  curriculum = db.relationship('Curriculum', lazy='joined')
```

I tried the following query. I got no attributes of my curriculum in my query

```
db.session.query(CurriculumAreaOfLearning).join(models.Curriculum, models.CurriculumAreaOfLearning.curriculumid == models.Curriculum.id)
```

I tried the following query. I get an error

```
db.session.query(CurriculumAreaOfLearning).join(models.Curriculum, models.CurriculumAreaOfLearning.curriculumid == models.Curriculum.id).add_columns(model.Curriculum.name)
```

AttributeError: type object 'CurriculumAreaOfLearninig' has no attribute 'Curriculum'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.session.query(CurriculumAreaOfLearning, Curriculum)
          .join(Curriculum, Curriculum.id == CurriculumAreaOfLearning.curriculumid).all()
```

Comment: I get an error: InvalidRequestError: Can't join table/selectable 'curriculum' to itself

Comment: Now I get .a different error: ArgumentError: Wildcard loader can only be used with exactly one entity